# How to Display 7 days of the week in Gridview Header from a Calendar

Tags: asp.net, gridview, calendar, header

I am trying to display the 7 days of the week inside GridView header so my code below shows how to get those days but I don't know how to put them in Gridview Header
with day of names of the week. About like image shows. I run ASP.NET with SQL SERVER EXPRESS database use sqldatasource connection to select all employees to a gridview.

```
foreach (DateTime selectedDateTime in Calendar1.SelectedDates)
{
    Response.Write(selectedDateTime.ToShortDateString() + " <br/>");
}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to create the headers or to fill the data for each row? According to your image, it looks as if you already have the headers. If not, then you should create the 7 columns in your markup.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thank you for reply. I want to create the headers and fill them with dates of the week. My problem is I don't know how to get to look like as that image. I can retriv dates but dont know how to show Employees in the first column then dates on the rest of Headers. Exactly as image shows. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the columns in the GridView this way:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeader="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Monday" HeaderText="Monday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thuesday" HeaderText="Thuesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Wednesday" HeaderText="Wednesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thursday" HeaderText="Thursday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Friday" HeaderText="Friday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Saturday" HeaderText="Saturday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunday" HeaderText="Sunday" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If no data is expected in the days of the week columns, you could use TemplateFields:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeader="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monday" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thuesday" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Wednesday" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thursday" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Friday" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saturday" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sunday" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```